# Resize img height according to div height

Tags: css, image, html, height

Hello everybody,

I have this CSS that acts weirdly and i dont' understand why. Please help undestand why:

THE CSS

```
html body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#000;
margin:0;
}


.top
{
margin-left:7.5%;
margin-right:7.5%;
height:8.1%;  width:85%;
position:relative;
border-bottom:#FFFFFF solid thin;
}
.top img
{
height:100%;
}
```

THE HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="top" align="center">
<img src="images/titlu_trans.png" alt="Sigla companie Calin Events"/>
</div>
```

Now Safari interpret's this correctly by setting the div height to 8.1% of the total resolution height and then the img height at 100% of the div height so at 8.1% of the viewing resolution. But Chrome, on a Windows machine does not and interprets this by setting the img's height at 100% of the viewing resolution height. Why is this happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "the viewing resolution"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to size both the html and the body.

Change `html body{` to `html, body{` (note the comma)

http://jsfiddle.net/FXhPZ/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with my latest Chrome using your code above. The image resized properly, proportional to the div.

Another solution is to set the image as background, and use

```
background-size: cover;
```

or

```
background-size: contain;
```

Note that this method only works in modern browsers. Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp